# functional equation $f(xy)=\frac{f(x)f(y)}{f(1)}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I am looking for functions $f$ (in my case $\mathbb{N}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+*}$) for which the ratio of the images only depends on the ratio of their antecedents :

$$\frac{f(n_1.n_0)}{f(n_2.n_0)}=\frac{f(n_1)}{f(n_2)} \forall (n_0,n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{N}^{*3}$$

Which is equivalent to
$$f(n_1.n_2)=\frac{f(n_1).f(n_2)}{f(1)} \forall (n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{N}^{*2}$$

It is obvious that $f(n)=c.n^m$ ($c \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$ and  $m \in \mathbb{R}$) validate that equation.

Can we prove that they are the only solutions ?

Comment: $$\log(f(e^{\log x+\log y}))=\log(f(e^{\log x}))+\log(f(e^{\log y}))-\log(f(e^{\log1}))$$ is equivalent to $g(u+v)=g(u)+g(v)-g(0)$, which expresses linearity (also affinity). But this is not the whole story, as your arguments are integer only.

Comment: Thank you @YvesDaoust, you convert the problem into the functional equation $g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)-g(0)$

Comment: Yes, I know :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't manage to prove that $g(0)=0$ :-/

Comment: $g(0)=0$ is not necessary.

Comment: OK, then $g(x+y) \neq g(x) + g(y)$ is not linear. If we write the equation with $h(x)=g(x)-g(0)$ then we have $h(x+y) = h(x)+h(y)$. I suppose it is a known that the only differentiable solutions of this functional equation are $h(x)=a.x$ so $g(x)=a.x+c$

Comment: I wrote "also affinity". If you only care about the natural solutions, the differentiability argument does not hold. I guess that there can be irregular solutions based on independent subsets of naturals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the initial identity, by induction

$$f(n)=f(p_0^{m_0}p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_k^{m_k})=\frac{f(p_0)^{m_0}f(p_1)^{m_1}\cdots f(p_k)^{m_k}}{f(1)^{m_0+m_1+\cdots m_k-1}}.$$

As the prime decomposition is unique, you can choose the $f(p_k)$ and $f(1)$ freely.

Answer (score 2):

One can find a more general class of solutions. Denote by $\mathcal{P}$ the set of primes and take an arbitrary sequence of real numbers $(m_p)_{p\in \mathcal{P}}$, then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, uniquely write $n$ as,
$$
n = p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_q^{\alpha_q}
$$
where $q \geq 0$, $p_1, ..., p_q \in \mathcal{P}$ and $\alpha_1, ... ,\alpha_q \in \mathbb{N}^*$, possibly having a void product if $n = 1$.

Then define $f$ by $f(n) = p_1^{m_{p_1}\alpha_1}...p_q^{m_{p_q}\alpha_q}$, we easily check that $f(n_1.n_2) = f(n_1).f(n_2)$. In general $f$ cannot be written $f(n) = c.n^m$ for some real numbers $c >0$,$m$.

The next question: Is this more general class, the only class of solutions ?

Comment: That is a great idea ! You consider the decomposition of n on the set of prime numbers then use each "coordinate" independently to build the function. By the way, maybe it would be clearer if we don't use the values $P_i$ in the expression of $f$. $f(n)=\prod {e^{\alpha_i m_i}}$ shows that we can treat each prime number independently of its value.

Comment: Yes of course, you can have a nice closed form for f with a "false" infinite product, as only a finite number of alpha's can be non-zero.